# Way to optimize my image slicing cffi based function

Tags: python, c, graphics, raylib, cffi

I'm using cffi and raylib to create a small game engine, i've just created a function that can slice an image, despite some improvements that have to be done, it's working well, therefore, my function is really slow.

```py
def slice(path, size):
    slices = []
    base_image = ffi.new("Image*", LoadImage(path.encode("ascii")))
    for y in range(0, base_image.height, size[1]):
        for x in range(0, base_image.width, size[0]):
            image = ffi.new("Image*", LoadImage(path.encode("ascii"))) #The problem is here
            ImageCrop(image, (x, y, x+size[0], y+size[1]))
            slices.append(image[0])
    return slices
```

When i tried to do this :

```py
def slice(path, size):
    slices = []
    base_image = ffi.new("Image*", LoadImage(path.encode("ascii")))
    for y in range(0, base_image.height, size[1]):
        for x in range(0, base_image.width, size[0]):
            image = base_image 
            ImageCrop(image, (x, y, x+size[0], y+size[1]))
            slices.append(image[0])
    return slices
```

or

```py
import copy
def slice(path, size):
    slices = []
    base_image = ffi.new("Image*", LoadImage(path.encode("ascii")))
    for y in range(0, base_image.height, size[1]):
        for x in range(0, base_image.width, size[0]):
            image = copy.copy(base_image) 
            ImageCrop(image, (x, y, x+size[0], y+size[1]))
            slices.append(image[0])
    return slices
```

it did'nt work.

Comment: it seems like you load again and again the same image. Maybe `ffi` has function to duplicate image instead of load it again. Or maybe you need to use `copy.deepcopy()` instead of `copy.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

How would you do that in C?  I'm not sure, but reading your piece of code, I would guess that maybe `Image` is the return type of the `LoadImage()` function (not `Image*` or anything else), whereas `ImageCrop()` takes a `Image* p_image` first argument.  It uses `*p_image` as input, crops it, and outputs the cropped image by writing the new `Image` inside `*p_image`.  I'm not sure, but this might be one of the many ways to do it in C.

In other words, and again this is a guess, in C you'd write code like this:

```
Image base_image = LoadImage(path);
for (...every slice...) {
    Image image_part = base_image;   // makes a copy of the Image data structure in C
    ImageCrop(&image_part, ...);
    // now 'image_part' contains the cropped image
}
```

If that is actually correct, then the CFFI version would be:

```
base_image = LoadImage(path.encode("ascii"))   # returns an Image
for ...:
    image_part = ffi.new("Image *", base_image)
    # ^^ makes a new 'Image' initialized with a copy of the data structure
    #    from base_image, and returns a pointer to that new Image
    ImageCrop(image_part, (...))
    images.append(image_part[0])
```